# how to recover a corrupt workspace in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

I had a corrupt workspace (due to svn collision).
I deleted the .metadata directory from the workspace, and then reloaded eclipse, and did an "import" of a *project* into the workspace.
However, the project got imported in a rather strange way -- all directories in the project appear, but the src/ directory does not have automatic compilation (when choosing a .java file) -- it is as if the src/ directory is not identified as a special directory.

Is there a way to fix that?

I also followed http://letsgetdugg.com/2009/04/19/recovering-a-corrupt-eclipse-workspace/, and that did not help either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All configuration data for your workspace is stored in `.metadata`.  Try to recover the deleted folder then fix the workspace.  Otherwise you will need to reconfigure everything.

You can salvage certain folders from `.metadata` to keep your preferences (e.g. key bindings) at least.

Answer (score 2):

Switch to a new workspace.

Then go File -> Import -> Exsisting projects into workspace .

In the root folder text box , type the address of corrupted  workspace.

Click Refresh .

Select the projects and click finish

Comment: You don't have to switch to a new workspace - I found it was enough to go into the file system and move `workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.resources` out of the way and Eclipse was happy. I had to import the projects again, as you say though, but it salvaged my window layout which is what I wanted.

Comment: Just had to retrieve the server configuration for tomcat which was stored in that directory as well, so worth backing it up and not deleting it....

Answer (score 0):

After importing your project, check your project properties, especially the entries in "Java Build Path". There you have to add the "src" directory as source folder. Maybe you also have to adjust the output folder and libraries you are using in your project.

Answer (score 0):

create a new project.
copy your pages ,library files,etc.
set build paths.
compile it. then others will be automatically created

Answer (score -1):

copy project to another (right click -> copy in eclipse)
new project created was correct for me in same situation and .class files repair .