# Why does my Eclipse workspace get so easily corrupted?

Tags: eclipse

I'm working with Eclipse 4.2 on OSX 10.8. Once in a while, Eclipse freezes and I have to force quit the application. Yes, programs freeze sometimes, that's not a huge problem. What is a problem, though, is that on the next start, Eclipse fails to load the workspace. It freezes on startup, or the workspace does not show up. It seems the workspace gets corrupted every time Eclipse is not shut down cleanly.

One way to fix the startup is

```
rm -rf ~/workspace/.metadata
```

After doing this, of course, settings are gone, projects have to be reimported etc. - It's really a pain, and I don't understand why it has to be this way. Other applications seem to be able to keep their data intact, even if they are killed.

Can you suggest ways to remedy this problem? Are there ways of recovering a corrupted workspace including the settings?

Comment: What 3rd party plugins have you installed and what kinds of files and apps do you build and with which tools? By the way, deleting the metadata in one swipe is problematic in its own way and should only be used as a last resort, if at all.

Comment: I use PyDev and CDT as well as plugins for Mercurial, Git and Subversion. I also use the Eclipse Color Theme plugin.
What would you recommend as an alternative to deleting the .metadata?

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8405123/how-to-recover-a-corrupt-workspace-in-eclipse

Comment: Not really a duplicate. In the first place, I want to know what causes workspace corruption, not just how to mitigate it. There was an answer explaining the problem (Eclipse's representation of the source) here, but it seems to have been deleted.